# send email with smtp client in c#

Tags: c#, smtp, pop3

I need to send emails from my Asp.net c# site, we are hosting on ovh, here what I did:

```
public static void Send(string stringFrom, string stringFromPass, 
        string stringTo, string stringBody, string stringSubject, int tryNb)
    {
        // Command line argument must the the SMTP host.
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mondomaine.me", 587);
        // Specify the e-mail sender. 
        // Create a mailing address that includes a UTF8 character 
        // in the display name.
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress(stringFrom,
           "Sender",
        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        // Set destinations for the e-mail message.
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress(stringTo);
        // Specify the message content.
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        message.Body = stringBody;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        message.Subject = stringSubject;
        message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        //provide Authentication Details need to be passed when sending email from gmail
        string password = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringFromPass));
        NetworkCredential mailAuthentication = new NetworkCredential(stringFrom, password);
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = mailAuthentication; 
        // Set the method that is called back when the send operation ends.
        client.SendCompleted += new
        SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
        // The userState can be any object that allows your callback  
        // method to identify this send operation. 
        // For this example, the userToken is a string constant. 
        string userState = stringFrom + "*&(k)&*" +
            stringFromPass + "*&(k)&*" + stringTo + "*&(k)&*" +
            stringBody + "*&(k)&*" + stringSubject + "*&(k)&*" + tryNb.ToString();
        client.SendAsync(message, userState);
    }
```

and then i'm calling this fonction whenever i need to. I'm receiving an ovh server response:

```
sorry, invalid MAIL FROM for open-smtp session (http://travaux.ovh.com/?do=details&id=2602)
```

on this last link they told that:

```
messages sent via open-smtp will only be accepted if the email address of the fields From / Sender is the same connection login used for POP access.
```

As you see in my code i'm not using POP and i dont know how to. so why this restriction ?
Any idea how to fix that will be much apreciated.

Comment: There is no issue with your code, the email is sending just fine it's the mail server configuration you need to sort out, it's probably not configured correctly for SMTP.

Comment: have you tried debugging the code also wrapping that code around a `try{}catch{}` may lead you to the real underlining issue

Comment: thank you for your response, i will see and try that.

Comment: Using outlook, i configured the mail server with all informations needed `ns0.ovh.net` `110` for `POP` and `ns0.ovh.net` `587` for `SMTP` with the `email` and the `password` for authentification, anything else to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was caused by the `mailAuthentication`, now i'm using `System.Security.SecureString` instead of `Convert.ToBase64String` to encode `passwords` and everything work well.

```
System.Security.SecureString secureString = new System.Security.SecureString();
stringFromPass.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(p => secureString.AppendChar(p));
NetworkCredential mailAuthentication = new NetworkCredential(stringFrom, secureString);
```

In outlook, you must configure your smtp to use email and password

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send throw `Gmail-Id`.

---

In your Email ID change the Email-setting

Follow these step

- Click 1  --> Setting
- Click 2  --> Forwarding and POP/IMAP
- Clect 3  --> Enable IMAP Access

---

Mailing function:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("Abc@Servername.com");
message.To.Add("Tosender@Servername.com");
message.Subject = "Your QR Code Image";
message.Body = "Please open this link and download this QR Code image for scanning your QRCode :" + QR_Code;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(message);
```

In WebConfig:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="abc@gmail.com" password="****" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```